# Remove Invalid Characters from string

Tags: java, php, excel, unicode, encoding

I am saving data to database using php, and exporting it using java

There are rows with some characters that cause problems when i create excel

I use this https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel package

There is no code errors but when i open xlsx i see this

[image: this is row with "\b" character]

[image: this is row with "\u0001" character]

Here are the characters : "\b" and "\u0001"

This are my database rows with this characters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb2jk.png)

[image][image]

When I copy the column from db and paste it to inteliji i see this
[image]

[image]

Is there any way to change the string encoding to avoild excel error, or to remove such bad characters using php when i save them to database or java when i export them

Comment: The library you are using for converting to Excel most probably cannot handle anything other than ASCII. And to your question "s there any way to change the string encoding".. No, because you don't have control over the external library.

Comment: @Nishit i mean to change encoding, or remove the characters before passing them to library

Comment: You have Chinese letters in your data. That means non ASCII characters. If you remove them, you lose the data.. This is not about an extra harmless backspace or space or new line character. The problem is your real data cannot be parsed by the library you are using.

Comment: @Nishit but chinese character are normaly parsed by the library,

Comment: when i remove "\b" from string everithing works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data contains non-printable characters "start of heading" and "backspace", which are valid in common charsets. Look at String.replaceAll() with a replacement of "". That will remove those characters. I leave it to you to construct a simple regular expression to search for them.